# What is the reason for the equality operator not producing an output of True/False after a split is applied on an empty string in powershell?

Tags: powershell

When I apply split on an empty string and then apply equality comparison, I do not get $True or $False (see below).

More strangely I see some invisible output when I compare the split result with the empty string while I do not see any output when I compare the split result with a nonempty string (see below).

```
PS > ''.split(',') -eq ''

PS > ''.split(',') -eq 'a'
PS > ''.split(',') -ne ''
PS > ''.split(',') -ne 'a'

PS >
```

What is the reason for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The split operation, even when applied to an empty string, produce an array of 1 element as a result. The reference [SS64 - Comparison Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html) explains this as:

> When applied to an array, comparison operators will work as a filter
>   returning all the values which match.

For instance, the following `@('a','b','c','a') -eq 'a'` will return the 2 elements that are equal to `a`

To have the correct results in your example, you'd have to count the number of elements are returned and check if there's any.

```
(''.split(',') -eq '').Count -ge 1 # Is True
(''.split(',') -eq 'a').Count -ge 1 # Is False
(''.split(',') -ne '').Count -ge 1 # Is False
(''.split(',') -ne 'a').Count -ge 1 # Is True
```

Comment: I did not know this filter behavior for arrays. It is a confusing design choice to override the eq operator like that but there is not much we can do about that. Now I understand the output I was getting. So for -eq '', I was getting the string '' so it was printing it on the screen, while for -ne '', I was getting no matching element; therefore, there was no output.